# How to automatically add signals in GTKwave when opened?

Tags: vhdl, simulation, vlsi

I use GHDL and GTKwave to compile/simulate and see the waveform of my VHDL code. Is there any way to automatically append signals in GTKwave's signals window when opened?

The problem is that I constantly make small changes in my design, and I have to reopen the simulation multiple times, so adding the signals by hand gets a bit tiring.

Comment: Not automatic but when you get the display looking the way you want it, "File/Write Save File". Then File/Read Save File to reload that setting for future simulations.

Comment: In case you don't know, there's a reload waveform option (Shift+Ctrl+R), so you don't have to close the window and open it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the current layout with *File*->*Write Save File* and specify the save file on the command line.

The save file contains a link to the data file, not the actual data, so the waveform will be current on open.

You can also leave gtkwave running and use *File*->*Reload Waveform* to update an existing view with new data.

My build scripts also call *vcd2fst* at the end to convert the VCD files to FST format, which is both smaller and pre-indexed for quicker loads, and atomically replaces the output files so it is always safe to reload (gtkwave does not like incomplete files).

Comment: is there a way to let GtkWave to automatically reload waveform when it updates, or reload for each specified time interval?